# How to change column type in mySQL from DATE to DATETIME

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to change a column from DATE to DATETIME in mySQL using sqlfiddle. But I'm just getting syntax errors, when looking at other stack overflow answers it seems like this method should work? What am I doing wrong? Is the only way (is it safer?) to add a new column, update new column with old and drop the old one?

My current method (assume there is data already in the table after creation)

```
CREATE TABLE re ( file_id INT NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, mydate DATE NOT NULL);

ALTER TABLE re alter column "mydate" DATETIME NOT NULL
```

The above doesn't work on sqlfiddle but it's the most common answer, other than the previous way. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, at least, one errors in you question:

1. `AUTO INCREMENT` should have an underscore between AUTO and INCREMENT.
2. The `ALTER TABLE` statement should be written with `MODIFY COLUMN`, and not with `ALTER COLUMN`.  (This is a possible bug in MySQL?)

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/pBvluxRX)

I created a bug-report for this: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=109461

P.S.:  the time part of the DATETIME field will be set to '00:00:00', see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/h3ObKJyf)

EDIT: Response from [22 Dec 13:36] MySQL Verification Team

> Thank you for your bug report.
>
> However, it is not a bug.
>
> Our Reference Manual clearly states that  ........ ALTER COLUMN
> ....... and ....... MODIFY COLUMN ..... have two very different
> scopes, with the first one being reduced to the changes for only
> couple of keywords.

Re-reading the docs, I read: [ALTER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html#:%7E:text=ALTER%3A%20Used%20only%20to%20change%20a%20column%20default%20value.): "Used only to change a column default value."

and [MODIFY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html#:%7E:text=MODIFY%3A,can%20reorder%20columns.) COLUMN

- Can change a column definition but not its name.
- More convenient than CHANGE to change a column definition without renaming it.
- With FIRST or AFTER, can reorder columns.